# $l_1$-metric and cut metric equivalence

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming, metric-spaces

I would like to show that the following two statements are equivalent.

Let $(A,d)$ be an $n$-point metric space and $B$ a set of $\binom{n}{2}$ pairs of points of $A$.

Then $\exists t \geq 1$, an integer $m$, and an embedding $f : A \rightarrow R^m$ s.t. 
$\forall x,y \in A$ : $d(x,y) \leq d_1(f(x), f(y)) \leq t\cdot d(x,y)$ where $d_1$ denotes the $l_1$ norm.

And the statement:

For every $a,b : B \rightarrow R^+$ such that
$$\sum_{(x,y) \in B} a(x,y)d(x,y) \leq \sum_{(x,y) \in B} b(x,y)d(x,y),$$
there exists a set $S \subseteq A$ (not empty, not equal to $A$), such that 
$$\sum_{(x,y) \in B} a(x,y)d_S(x,y) \leq \sum_{(x,y) \in B} b(x,y)d_S(x,y)$$
where $d_S$ is the cut metric of the set S.

I understand that minimizing the $l_1$ metric is the same as minimizing the cut metric.
Thus my idea was to formulate the first statement as a Linear Program but I didn't get any useful insights out of it.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks andy

Comment: by ncr(n,2) i mean n choose 2

Comment: @andy: I typeset "n choose 2" for you.  The LaTeX code is \binom{n}{2}.

Comment: Isn't the first statement always true (assuming $d(x,y) = 0$ implies $x = y$, otherwise it's plainly false)? Choose the images $f(A)$ to be far apart (farther than the largest $d(x,y)$), and choose $t$ to be large enough. This works even for $m = 1$.

Comment: Also, what's the cut metric?

Comment: Given a Graph G=(V,E) a cut metric §d_S§ for a subset S of the nodes assign a distance of one to all node pairs for which the edge crosses S and $\bar{S}$ and 0 else.

Comment: @Yuval: No its not, d can be any distance, for example the "edit distance", for which it is known that it has an $\Omega(\log n)$ embedding into l1

Comment: @andy: This is consistent with your definition, which just states that $t$ exists. It doesn't constrain it as a function of $n$.

Comment: hmm, i interpreted the "exists t"-statement as f having distortion t